# Data from text file reading as 0/Null

Tags: c, text-files

I'm writing a C program to read data from 2 text files and merge them into 1 text file. When reading the text file, I print the values to make sure I'm getting the right values out but all that come up are either 0 or Null.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define str_len 100

//Question 2A
typedef struct {
  int atmNum;
  char name[str_len];
  char symbol[str_len];
  float atmWeight;
} PeriodocElement;

void SortedMergedFile (FILE *file1, FILE *file2);

int main () {
  FILE *file1;
  file1 = fopen("1.txt", "r");
  FILE *file2;
  file2 = fopen("2.txt", "r");

  if (file1 == NULL) {
    printf("FILE 1 DOES NOT EXIST\n");
  }
  if (file2 == NULL) {
    printf("FILE 2 DOES NOT EXIST\n");
  }
  else {
    SortedMergedFile(file1, file2);
  }
}

void SortedMergedFile (FILE *file1, FILE *file2) {
  PeriodocElement elements [150];
  int i = 0;

  while (i != 4) {
    fscanf(file1, "%d  %s  %s %f", &elements[i].atmNum, elements[i].name, elements[i].symbol, &elements[i].atmWeight);
    i++;

    printf("\n%d %s %s %4.2f", elements[i].atmNum, elements[i].name, elements[i].symbol, elements[i].atmWeight);
  }
}
```

And here is the text file:

```
08  Serium  Se 40.08
20  Sodium  Na 22.99
45  gatium  Ga 23.90
56  Manion  Ma 45.99
```

If anyone could spot anything I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try also printing the return values of fscanf for debugging.

Comment: I suspect the `"."`, the one in the format specifier, wreaking some havoc. What happens if you replace it with `" "` ? I.e. a blank.

Comment: @Yunnosch My bad, its supposed to read "%d  %s  %s %f" . I corrected it and still get the same error.

Comment: If you init the array elements with non-null, recognisable values, are they what gets printed? It would mean that fscanf totally failed.

Comment: @Yunnosch Its working now, I was incrementing i before printing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are reading the components of `element[i]`.
2. Then you increment `i`.
3. Then you print the components of `element[i]` (which `i` is now one greater), and *those* are of course not yet initialized.

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe I missed that.